# How can I update a row only if the new value is larger than the existing value in the column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-update

I am currently doing in my application code:

```
date = obj->execute("SELECT date FROM table WHERE id=123");  
if(date < someDate) {  
    obj->executeUpdate("UPDATE table set date=? where id=123",someDate);  
}
```

I.e. I update `date` on a row only if it is smaller than some new date variable in my application.
Is there a way to do this directly in SQL?
E.g. something like:

```
UPDATE table  
set date = IF(date < ?, date, ?) where id = 123
```

Anything that works regardless of prepared statement

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table SET date=value WHERE date<value AND id=123;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a where criteria:

```
UPDATE table SET date = ? WHERE ID = 123 AND date < ?;
```